# Align images horizontally on desktop and vertically on mobile

Tags: html, css, shopify

I have 4 images on my website that I want  to display horizontally on desktop and vertically on mobile. (I just started learning HTML so I **basically know nothing about coding**)

The only thing I could think of was to find a way to set that a number of images will align themselves next to each other as long as there's room for them.

So I've set the width of each image to 24%. It worked perfectly on desktop but then of course on mobile they were also horizontal as on desktop

```
    <div>

<img src="xxx.jpg" width="24%">

<img src="yyy.jpg" width="24%">

<img src="zzz.jpg" width="24%">

<img src="ccc.jpg" width="24%">

</div>
```

After looking for a solution I learned about the float tag and tried the following

```
    <div>

<img src="xxx.jpg" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">

<img src="yyy.jpg" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">

<img src="zzz.jpg" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">

<img src="ccc.jpg" style="float: left; width: 24%; margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 0.5em;">

</div>
```

But again the same thing happened. It shows the images horizontally on mobile.

Anyone knows a solution to this?

I'm using shopify to host my website if it helps.

Comment: Why not use bootstrap?

Comment: post some code that you tried

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries, also don't forget https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here ur work is done..run this code on ur browser. here media queries is used for mobile display. u should learn that how to make responsive ur website for ur concerned question. work hard :)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.img {
display:inline;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.img {
display:block;
} }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img">
<img src="xxx.jpg" width="200px" height="300px">
<img src="yyy.jpg" width="200px" height="300px">   
<img src="zzz.jpg" width="200px" height="300px">    
<img src="ccc.jpg" width="200px" height="300px">   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you wrap your images into li or

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
   img {display:block;width:100% !important}
}
```

Comment: Sorry as I mentioned I know very little code. I'm using  shopify, I assume the code you suggested is css, so I referenced the section as "whyyou" (p class="whyyou") and then pasted the following code in my theme.css.liquid "p.whyyou {
   img {display:block;width:100%}
}" Unfortunately they are displayed vertically

Comment: why p.whyyou  ?, you can paste whole code in your css file

Comment: How can I then control where the image is displayed?

Comment: you dont need to do anything just paste above code into your css file or in html file inside <style> tag

Comment: I did it kinda messed up other images on the front page

Comment: add a class "responsive" to your images's parent div like this <div class="responsive"> then use .responsive img {display:block;width:100% !important}